# Deploying multiple contracts using Hardhat

Tags: solidity, hardhat, hardhat-deploy

My two contracts look something like this:

```
contract ContractA {
        ContractB public contractB;
     
     constructor() {
            contractB = new ContractB(address(this));
    }
}

contract ContractB{

      address public tokenAddress;
         constructor(address _tokenAddress) {
                tokenAddress = _tokenAddress;
         }
}
```

This is my Hardhat deploy script:

```
async function main() {
 
  const ContractA = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("ContractA");
  const contractA = await ContractA.deploy();

  await contractA.deployed();

}
```

When I deploy this in the Read Contract value I see the address of contract B, but it's just a plain address is not a contract that I can verify and see the functions. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your deployment script (the default being sample-script.js), you should do:

```
const contractA= await ethers.getContractFactory(ContractA); 
const contractAcontract= await contractA.deployed();
await contractAcontract.deployed();

const contractB = await ethers.getContractFactory(ContractB); 
const contractBcontract = await contractB.deployed(contractAcontract.address);
await contractBcontract.deployed();
```

I'd say you need to deploy both contracts, not just **contractA**.

EDIT:

I was right about deploying both contracts, although you need to pass the first contract's address as an argument to the second one. Found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69812460/how-to-deploy-multiple-smart-contracts-using-hardhat-deploy). Hope that solves it for you.

Comment: Hi, you need to pass the address as a parameter in the contractB. I already tried that method but contractB address in the contractA is different than contractB deployed.

Comment: @JohnDoeMighty I've updated my answer, hope that solves it for you.